# Diseño de Diagrama UML de clases - dudas

Tags: java, diseño, uml

Estoy diseñando un diagrama UML para en un futuro implementarlo en Java. Me gustaría incorporar algunas librerías de Java ejemplo Date. Tambien como se incorporaran interfaces. Alguien me podrá ayudar en poder entender como integrar u/o mostrar una librería en my diagrama UML? El proyecto que estoy realizando es un calendario, algo similar al de apple calender. Donde el usuario pueda agregar eventos (tiempo de inicio y final), ajustar hora y minutos de eventos, poder hacer los eventos repetitivos, remover un evento, que el calendario soporte usuarios multiples, cambiar de light a dark theme etc.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que deberías explicar a qué [tipo de diagrama UML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_unificado_de_modelado#Tipos_de_diagramas_en_UML_2.5) te refieres e idealmente mostrar lo que ya has hecho.

Comment: Hola, es un diagrama uml de clases.

Comment: Si lo que estas tratando de modelar es un diagrama de clases integrando librerías, entonces representa las librerías como clases, represando los atributos y métodos que vayas a utilizar, de este modo le darás sentido a tu diagrama, esta es la manera sencilla.

Comment: Gracias asi es como le hice y en otras solo especifique en mi documentation que libreria ocupe y su metodo. Buen dia!